# How can I run a .ipynb notebook from mac, potentially with a docker or VM?

Tags: python, macos, docker, jupyter-notebook, gcloud

I am loading the python notebook through Google Collab and it seems to run local commands which some of them (gsutil, from gcloud sdk) fail, with mac / python / extensions specific issues.
This is why I am thinking that a Linux virtual box or container may help me mount the local notebooks and try to run them in that linux context,
Would this be possible? What advice do you have for me?
thanks,
Nicolae